# Mysql INNER JOIN and Resource #9

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am working on a UCP(User control panel) where a user loggs in by an unique ID that is given at registration.
My problem is i have two tables in my database:

> serverplayers - Holds user ID and name and all of his info

and

> vehicles - holds vehicle owner and vehicle model.

So what I need to do is connect those two together by users "Username".I tried Mysql INNER JOIN like this.

```
$car = mysql_query('SELECT vehicles.vOwner, vehicles.vModel 
FROM vehicles 
INNER JOIN serverplayers ON vehicles.vOwner = serverplayers.User 
WHERE vehicles.vOwner = '.$ro['User'].'');
```

After this I get Recourse #9, i read that it's not an error it's just that the result is empty?I may have error's or problems in my mysql query so please tell everything whats wrong.

But what's the problem I think is that a vehicle is only connected by it's owner's name and doesn't contain UserID.So what I need is basically show a User what car he has by Connecting his username with vOwner.I'm not a very bright boy when it comes to mysql or php I'm just learning and I came across this thing as mysql INNER JOINS that I think is very usefull(but the main reason is that I don't want to recode the whole server and the UCP).

Vehicles:

[image: Vehicles table]

ServerPlayers:

[ServerPlayers table http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/3369/qebq.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/3369/qebq.png)

Comment: Is `vehicles.vOwner` just the owner's name?  If you can you really need to use a unique reference to the owner rather than a name that can be duplicated.  You risk getting into quite a mess with your current database architecture.

Comment: Here's my `vehicles` structure.
http://i.imgur.com/HLSXvYC.png
And here's my `serverplayers` structure.
http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/3369/qebq.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not  sure what `$ro['User']` is, but it sounds like an ID based on your question.  In that case I would just switch `vehicles.vOwner` to `serverplayers.UserID` in that comparison.  I would also highly recommend changing your schema so `vOwner` *is* the ID and not the username (what if the username changes in one of the tables?)  It also doesn't look like you need to join on serverplayers for anything.

The "resource" is a mysql results resource.  You can't get anything out of it just by looking at it -- you need to run fetch operations on it:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($car);
```

---

I recommend using PDO or mysqli over the deprecated ext/mysql.

Comment: $ro['User'] stands for user's Username not his ID.

Comment: @Kirilas in that case why do you need the join

Comment: Because if the vehicles we're saved by owner's ID I would'nt need the JOIN wereas in this case it's saved by username and the user log's in by his ID.So I can't say that `SELECT vModel FROM vehicles WHERE vOwner = id` because the ID is ant integer(a number) and `vOwner` is his username and that won't match.I dont know how to get past it or if there is an easeier way, but Im willing to find out...